# Trying to encrypt and decrypt a vigenere cipher

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, vigenere

I have a text file that I already encrypted using shifting, but I need to encrypt the encrypted text again but this time using vigenere cipher. I then need to decrypt that encrypted text (vigenere first then shifting) but all the upper and lower case letters need to stay the same as well as the black spaces, quotes, commas, and full stops. I already completed the shift encryption and decryption all that is left is the vigenere. Below shown is my class for encrypting Vigenere, I have not written the decryption yet because I was stuck in the encryption step.
Thank you.

```
public static String vigenereEncryption(String str,String keyword)
{
char [] c_arr = null;
int g =0;
int keyLength = keyword.length();
String encrypted = "";
String update ="";
String []list = null;
for(int k = 0; k<keyword.length();k++){
char key = keyword.charAt(k);
 c_arr = keyword.toCharArray();
update = update + key;
}
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{



    //stores ascii value of character in the string at index 'i'
    int c=str.charAt(i);
    //encryption logic for uppercase letters

    if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
    {
        for(int k = 0; k<keyword.length();k++){
            g = c_arr[k] ;

        }
        c=(c+g)%26;
        //if c value exceeds the ascii value of 'Z' reduce it by subtracting 26(no.of alphabets) to keep in boundaries of ascii values of 'A' and 'Z'
        if(c>'Z')
            c=c-26;
    }
    //encryption logic for lowercase letters
    else if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
    {
        c=(c+g)%26;
        //if c value exceeds the ascii value of 'z' reduce it by subtracting 26(no.of alphabets) to keep in boundaries of ascii values of 'a' and 'z'
        if(c>'z')
            c=c-26;
    }



    //concatinate the encrypted characters/strings
    encrypted=encrypted+(char) c;
}
return encrypted;}}//end of public class`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looping over the keyword inside the loop for the text. That is not necessary.

You can find implementations of Vigenere Cipher [at rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#Java). 
Modify the following code for Java as per your needs (like checking for upper/lower case and processing them accordingly):

```
    static String encrypt(String text, final String key) {
        String res = "";
        text = text.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
            res += (char)((c + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'A') % 26 + 'A');
            j = ++j % key.length();
        }
        return res;
    }

    static String decrypt(String text, final String key) {
        String res = "";
        text = text.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
            res += (char)((c - key.charAt(j) + 26) % 26 + 'A');
            j = ++j % key.length();
        }
        return res;
    }
```